# Swift OS X run function on return of segue

Tags: cocoa, swift, segue

Using segues with OS X and swift, is there a method that gets called on the return from a segue? I've looked at the [NSViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/) and [NSSeguePerforming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSeguePerforming_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSSeguePerforming) docs but can't see anything promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in case this is helpful to anyone else; I made some kind of delegate protocol:

```
protocol JNCommunicationDelegate {
    func doAction(sender: AnyObject, message: AnyObject)
}
```

And then added a variable to the view controller that sends the message:

```
var communicationDelegate: JNCommunicationDelegate?
func setCommunicationDelegate(delegate: JNCommunicationDelegate) {
    self.communicationDelegate = delegate
}
```

(A more Swift way of doing this would be to have no setter.. but that's just too much Java on my part.) And then when the segue starts in the first controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let destination = segue.destinationController as MyViewControllerController
    destination.setCommunicationDelegate(self)
}
```

And then run the `doAction:` method from the second controller.

Answer (score 0):

no a segue defines ONE transition from ViewController A to ViewController B.
a segue has no life-time beyond that transition.

You have to manually add that functionality - e.g. via delegation pattern

Comment: So how would I go about that? Can I add an action to the button that dismisses the view controller in the 'first' view controller?